# how we can achive these functionality on image uploading

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

My task is:

Step 1a: User uploads the image

Input: Original size of image (fixed width variable height) – it can be of any dimension.

Limitation:

A. TYPE: JPG /  BMP / PNG etc

B.  MAX DIMENSION

-example 1024X1024px.

Step 1b: After upload, the system checks the criteria matching with our criteria.

Criteria : CHECKS MAX DIMENSIONS

If Yes:

If matches criteria ask user to create thumbnail image of size(145 x 190)

If No:

Again ask user to re size image until it fits in our criteria

Final OUTPUT:

2) 145 x 190 (Search result Image)(thumbnail)

3) 30% thumbnail

4) For profile pic we will define fixed width depending on which height will vary.(width not decided yet)

---

This Is my task .
In these task i am able to achive image upload ,check dimention . But not step wise . please help me to achive this task. I am New in Jquery only have 1 month of experience and this task is very complicated for me..
Hope you understand my Question.

My coading is(for checking dimention):
html:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

jQuery:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;


    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


    }

});
```

My coading is(for upload image):
Html:

Jquery:

```
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(thumbWidth)
                        .height(thumbHeight);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Also mention what the server language is

Comment: Pls review edited code

Comment: please help if you got the ans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution(not completely but hope it helps you some where)

html:

```
<p>image is set to 100x100 pixels!</p>

<img id="draggable" src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" />

<div id="dim"></div>
```

jquery:

```
var img     = document.getElementById('draggable'),
    new_img = new Image();

new_img.onload = function() {
    var img_width  = this.width,
        img_heigth = this.height;

    document.getElementById('dim').innerHTML = 'Original dimensions are : ' + img_width + 'x' + img_heigth + ' pixels';
}

new_img.src = img.src;
```

css:

```
#draggable {height: 100px; width: 100px;}
```